# Iniciar la aplicación con ventana maximizada con MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui

A quien maneje mejor la tecnología Blazor Server MAUI, el objetivo era una aplicación de escritorio de windows en principio.
Queremos que esa aplicación arranque siempre maximizada para aprovechar bien los espacios.
Que reducir el tamaño de la pantalla sea una opción.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new MainPage();

    }
}
```

Entiendo que es probable que el atributo MainPage se pueda usar para este fin, pero no encuentro no encuentro como. He detectado un enum que posiblemente sea el cual tenga que usar para esto pero no sé como asignarlo ni donde o como usarlo "ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized".

Cualquier ayuda se agradece. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca esto en el MauiProgram

#if WINDOWS

```
            builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
            {
                events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>
                {
                    wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
                    {
                        IntPtr nativeWindowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
                        WindowId win32WindowsId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(nativeWindowHandle);
                        AppWindow winuiAppWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(win32WindowsId);
                        if (winuiAppWindow.Presenter is OverlappedPresenter p)
                            p.Maximize();
                        else
                        {
                            const int width = 1200;
                            const int height = 800;
                            winuiAppWindow.MoveAndResize(new RectInt32(1920 / 2 - width / 2, 1080 / 2 - height / 2, width, height));
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

#endif

Comment: Gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 0):

Yo sobre escribí este método sobre el archivo App.xaml.cs dentro de la clase App

```
protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
{
    this.window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);

    var screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen;

    window.Width =  screen.Bounds.Width;
    window.Height = screen.Bounds.Height - 40; //los 40 que se le restan es por el espacio de la barra de windows abajo

    window.MinimumWidth= screen.Bounds.Width;
    window.MinimumHeight = screen.Bounds.Height;

    window.X=0;
    window.Y=0;

    return window;
}
```

De igual manera recomiendo la forma presentada por Christian Zaragoza